# Tool Tip for ribbon control

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

I have used `Ribbon` control in my project, and in that ribbon control I have used many buttons and labels.

For example I have used new_btn for creating a new folder under root, for this button I have set the tooltip property as "New Folder".

While moving mouse to this button, the tooltip does not display.  However, for normal buttons where I have set tooltip it displayed properly while hovering the mouse over the button.

How to use the tooltip for ribbon control items properly?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`ToolTipTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolservice.tooltiptitle.aspx) property. Apart from this property, you can also use five other properties to make the ToolTip more informative

- [ToolTipDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolservice.tooltipdescription.aspx)
- [ToolTipImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolservice.tooltipimagesource.aspx)
- [ToolTipFooterTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolservice.tooltipfootertitle.aspx)
- [ToolTIpFooterDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolservice.tooltipfooterdescription.aspx)
- [ToolTIpFooterImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribboncontrolservice.tooltipfooterimagesource.aspx)